# Is this path finding problem in a 01-matrix NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np

> **The problem:**
>
> *Input*: An $n \times n$ matrix of 0's and 1's, and a position *pos* of this matrix (i.e. a pair of integers $i,j$ with $1 \leq i,j \leq n$)
>
> *Output*:
>
> YES if there exists a path through **adjacent** matrix entries $\dagger$, starting at *pos*, covering each matrix entry with a 1 **exactly once**, and not covering the matrix entries with a 0.
>
> NO otherwise.

$\dagger$ a matrix entry is adjacent to the one immediately to its left, to the one immediately to its right, to the one immediately upwards and the one immediately below.

---

Informally, the matrix can be seen as a labyrinth where the 0's are walls, you start somewhere, and you have to walk through the whole maze without repeating any position.

Example input:

```
1100
1100
0000
0001
Pos: (1,1)
```

Corresponding output:

```
No (because you can't reach the position (4,4))
```

---

Is this problem NP-complete? If it is, what other NP-complete problem has been reduced to it? If it isn't, what approach can I use to design an efficient algorithm?

I think this is a particular case of the hamiltonian path problem (except that you have a fixed starting point). The graph can be constructed by taking the matrix entries with 1's as vertices. 2 vertices are adjacent iff their corresponding matrix entries are adjacent. So I think that reducing this problem to the hamiltonian path problem should be easy. Of course, to prove it is NP-complete, we would have to do the reduction backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to determine if there is a Hamiltonian path in a grid graph (an induced subgraph of a rectangular grid). This is **NP**-complete: see Itai, Papadimitriou and Szwarcfiter, *Hamilton Paths in Grid Graphs* (SIAM J. Comput., 11(4):676–686, 1982) [PDF](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/Hamilton-paths.pdf).

Comment: Does the fact that there is a fixed entry point change this result?

Comment: @nmamg Good point. The reduction in Ital *et al.* creates graphs with long "strips" of squares between vertex gadgets; there's probably enough space to add an edge to a vertex of degree 1, to force the path to start in a specific place.